# Secure file download in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have created a module in magento where the admin can upload a file to the web server and save the path on the DB.

On the front-end, I have created a link on the customer dashboard to download the file. I am able to download the file successfully however I'm unsure if the link was secure from hackers.

The full path goes like this

```
www.mydomain.com/media/folder1/folder2/file.name
```

and the download code goes like this

```
<a href="<?php Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'folder1/folder2/'.$nameFromDb ?> download">Download here</a>
```

My problem is that, when someone knows the path, they can access the file even if they are not login or a member.

QUESTION:

Is there a way I can hide or disguise the path/link?

What are the best way I can make the file secure from intruders?

I am willing to use javascript/jquery or php to secure the file.

Comment: Generally, the media folder is (A) publicly accessible and (B) not the place to store sensitive data. You may consider storing it in a private location or in the database and using a controller to authenticate the user, then load and serve the file instead of letting the browser handle all of that.

Comment: Thanks @Robbie Averill for your answer. Can you give me an example or link to follow. I have no idea on how to authenticate it on the controller.